# How to Activate RawImage on button click in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I just started learning Unity and trying to create a Video Gallery, for now I created a button with the Red Cross shown on the image. And the bigger rectangle is a raw image that holds my video. [image: Buttons and videos]
I would like to add a thumbnail on the button and on click the button the RawImage will start the corresponding video. For now it is working as mentioned but if only I activate the RawImage. I don't want the RawImage to be seen before I click the button.

For now this is what I have;

```
    RawImage rawImage1;
    public void StartVideoOne()
    {
        rawImage1.SetActive(true);
        videoPlayer.Play();

    }
```

But if I try to activate the RawImage during button onClick call this does not start the video. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How have you assigned a value to rawimage? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use `SetActive` on `RawImage` reference, it has to be a `GameObject`. I assume though you only put it in the code snippet so it's clear to see what's going on.

I set up a `VideoPlayer` in simple test project and your code worked just fine to activate the object and play the video, so here are a few things you might have missed:

- Have you checked that your button works? Do you have `GraphicRaycaster` component in your canvas? Did you subscribe to button's `onClick` event, either via inspector or code? Do you have `EventSystem` on scene?
- If your render mode in `VideoPlayer` is Render Texture, did you assign your `RawImage` as Target Texture?

This is an example of what you need to have: [image]

And code:

```
public class PlaybackController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button playButton;
    public RawImage rawImage1;
    public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        playButton.onClick.AddListener(StartVideoOne);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        playButton.onClick.RemoveListener(StartVideoOne);
    }

    private void StartVideoOne()
    {
        rawImage1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```